# C++ - static const variable initialization from .ini file with boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, boost, static, constants, boost-propertytree

For reading INI configuration file `boost:property_tree` can be used in the way as follows:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

int main()
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("config.ini", pt);
    int N = pt.get<int>("Section.ValueOfN");
```

However I have a class `Class` which has a static const variable `N`. The variable is static because there are millions of instances of this class and I do not need each `Class` to remember the value of `N` while it is constant and the same for each of them.

If variable `Class::N` is static const int, then I declare it in *Class.hpp* and define it in *Class.cpp* this way:

```
//Class.hpp
class Class
{
    static const int N;
}

//Class.cpp
const int Class::N = 42;
```

But what if I want to load it from a configuration file? `N` is static variable and as such it has to be defined out of any function. On the other side I have to define `property_tree` inside of function, but if it is inside of function I can't use it to define static const variable.

If it would be this way:

```
//Class.hpp
class Class
{
    static const int N;
}

//Class.cpp

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("config.ini", pt);
const int Class::N = pt.get<int>("Section.ValuOfN");
```

I would get an error on the line with `read:ini`:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

I can solve it this way:

```
//Class.hpp
class Class
{
    static const int N;
}

//Class.cpp

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

namespace {
int getFromINI(const std::string& section, const std::string& value)
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("config.ini", pt);
    return pt.get<int>(section + "." + value);
}
}

// Define constant static variables
const int Class::N = getFromINI("Section","ValueOfN");
```

As you can see, this is not an ideal solution. I have to make an `property_tree` for each static const variable I want to define and the tree is used only once. And of course I have to improve `getFromINI` function to be able to read other types than int.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Firstly, yes this is the best you can do (using anonymous lambda for extra conciseness). Also: Do NOT make that global static. Thank us later

Comment: When you say "make an property_tree for each static const variable I want to define" do you have lots of variables - and lots of instances? I wonder if there's another way of looking at the design rather than solving tis specific question

Comment: Perhaps just make a global that reads an entire INI section, exposing individual values as the members.